# Docker Container fail to run the spring native executable built using GraalVM

Tags: dockerfile, docker-container, graalvm, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, native-executable

I have built a simple REST API using springboot3 and graalVM runtime. I am trying to dockerize the same app and run locally. But upon running the container I get error
exec /app: exec format error. I am using mac M1 and trying to run docker container locally.

This is my Dockerfile

```
#FROM container-registry.oracle.com/os/oraclelinux:8-slim
#FROM scratch
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base

EXPOSE 8080
COPY build/native/nativeCompile/nativeimage app
ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```

Docker image inspection

```
 "Architecture": "arm64",
        "Os": "linux",
```

I could run my native executable but expecting to be run as a docker container too. I am using gradle build too hence finding it difficult how to build native image inside a container?

Comment: https://github.com/nehurane/springboot3-nativeimage

Comment: Is your native image a Mac or Linux binary? If it's Mac, it won't run inside a Linux container

Comment: native image is Mac bases. I am not getting where exactly I should mentioning that it should use mac binary. Means what base image I should use for docker container?

Comment: Added a multi stage build Dockerfile and now I am stuck on >>
failed to compute cache key: f
ailed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkitmount2766813902/build/native/nativeCompile: 
lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2766813902/build/native/nativeCompile: no such file or directory